# CherryPy auto mount Web Services by watching filesystem directory

Tags: python, web-services, cherrypy, apache-karaf

I am using [CherryPy](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to run a set of Web Services.

I want to separate each Web Service with one another, see [Microservices](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html).

Let's assume that I have each Web Service, written in a class in a single file (one class per file).

Also, let's assume that I put each Service file in a folder (e.g. named "services").

Is it possible, with CherryPy and maybe using decorators, to monitor the "services" folder and automatically deploy or update the services defined in this folder?

I am looking for something similar to what does the [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/) container.

Comment: [TornadoWeb](http://www.tornadoweb.org/)?

Comment: Thanks @earcam, could you please elaborate on that and make it an answer? Maybe with a small example? Thanks

Comment: I'm not a Python person so no short example sorry.  TornadoWeb seems to offer the ability to construct the server (including request handlers etc), so in this case you could write your own handler and manage the dynamic delegation yourself?  Just a guess but AFAIK you cannot do want you want with WSGI.